# Program drops com port while receiving data from arduino VB.net

Tags: vb.net, arduino, serial-port

When running the code the program will run to complete one cycle, then the arduino must be disconnected and reconnected (unplugged and replugged in) in order to run again. Sometimes the program will even stop halfway through.

I am very new to VB programming and any help would be appreciated

There is no problem with the arduino code, it was fully tested before creating the VB user form. 
tried running on multiple computers/Operating systems same results

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    ''reads data from arduino
    Dim datastream As String

    datastream = (SerialPort1.ReadLine)
    '' RichTextBox1.Text = datastream

    Data_manipulate(arr:=datastream)
End Sub

Public Sub Data_manipulate(ByRef arr As String)
    ''processes data to calculate linearity
    Dim linearity As Single
    Dim percent As Single
    Dim nominal As Single
    ReDim Preserve points(i)
    ReDim Preserve counts(i)
    Dim values As String() = arr.Split(New Char() {","c})
    percent = values(0) / values(3)
    nominal = values(1) / values(2)
    linearity = (percent - nominal) * 100
    TextBox3.Text = values(2) * (0.00118)
    points(i) = linearity
    counts(i) = nominal * 100
    TextBox8.Text = (points).max
    TextBox10.Text = points.Min
    Chart1.Series("Linearity").Points.AddXY(counts(i), points(i))
    ''Chart1.Series("Linearity").Points.AddXY(counts(i), points(i))
    If points.Max > NumericUpDown1.Value Then
        TextBox8.BackColor = Color.Red

    End If
    If points.Min < -NumericUpDown1.Value Then
        TextBox10.BackColor = Color.Red

    End If
    If nominal < 0.5 Then
        TextBox13.Text = values(1) * (0.00118)
        Dim Halfpercent As Double = values(1) * 0.00118
        If ((0.5 * (values(2) * 0.00118)) - 0.015) < Halfpercent AndAlso Halfpercent < ((0.5 * (values(2) * 0.00118)) + 0.015) Then
            TextBox13.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        Else TextBox13.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If

    End If
    If percent = 1 Then
        Auto_Slope_And_Level_Button_Click()

    End If
    i += 1

End Sub

Private Sub Connect_Button_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connect_Button.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Port")
        Return
    End If
    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
    SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    If Connect_Button.Text = "Connect" Then
        Try
            SerialPort1.Open()
            Connect_Button.Text = "Connected"
            Disconnect_Button.Text = "Disconnect"
            Connect_Button.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Else

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Start_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Start_Button.Click
    If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
        Chart1.Series("Linearity").Points.Clear()
        ReDim points(0)
        ReDim counts(0)

        SerialPort1.Write(1)
        TextBox8.Text = 0
        TextBox10.Text = 0
        TextBox2.Text = 0

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Connected")
        Return
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Disconnect_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Disconnect_Button.Click

    Try
        SerialPort1.Close()
        Disconnect_Button.Text = "Disconnected"
        Connect_Button.Text = "Connect"
        Connect_Button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

    Try
    For Each port As String In SerialPort.GetPortNames
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(port)
        Next
        ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ""
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

A "com port does not exist" error will occur if you don't reset between runs. 
If the program stops partway through the computer needs either a log-off or restart to reconnect with the arduino.

Comment: I would put something in the Catch of the Connect method and embed the code of the Start method in a try catch block. And see what happens.

Comment: Is "SerialPort1.Write(1)" correct? This should send to arduino 2 bytes of 0x31, 0x00. Insert "Option Strict On" at the beginning of the source and fix any errors that are detected. In addition, Are there any commands to instruct arduino to terminate communication before closing the port?

Comment: I have completed both of your suggestions to no avail. I added a try catch with a message box command. There is no stop communication for the Arduino, but it fails to even complete the first loop sometimes.

Comment: For example, what about trying to see what happens if Connect/Disconnect/Start is performed only after reading and discarding data (about console output) without calling data processing functions?